# Take a input from a scanner and use that as a name to a variable

Tags: java

I am wondering if I can take a input from a scanner, make a `String` of that value and then make a variable with that name. For example

```
System.out.println("What is this variable's name??");
String customName = input.next(); 

int (customName) = 0;
```

So that the name of the int is the users input.

Comment: Not in the same class or any other already compiled class. You can, however, generate a new class, compile it and use it without restarting JVM. However, it may be useful to know the use case better.

Comment: If you are looking for mapping of `String` to `Integer` take a look at `Map`s. For instance with `Map<String, Integer> mapping = new HashMap<>();` you can `mapping.put("foo", 42);` `mapping.put("bar", 123);` and now `mapping.get("foo")` will return `42`. You can reassign new value to same key by another `mapping.put("foo", 321);`.

Comment: @SreeKumar I am essentially making a school simulator program and in the meny one of the options are to add a student, the student is a class that has two values in it but I think thats irrelevant. I do know other ways to solve this problem but I was just wondering if it's possible to solve it in this way.

Comment: Java does not allow you to use arbitrary strings as variable names.  Java is not equivalent to JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for [variable variables](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php). Java does not support variable variables. You can create a `Map`/`HashMap` that have `String` as key and `Integer` as value. Like

```
Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
map.put(yourString, yourInterger);
//map.get(yourString) returns the Integer
```

I know this is not even close to variable variables, but this is as far as you can go with Java in terms of variable variables.